# Can't tell if gzip is on

Tags: http, browser, request, gzip, frontend

I'm a front-end developer and I'm doing performance tests on a site. When I run YSlow, it says that I should compress components with gzip.

The backend guy said that compress is on, however when I run YSlow again it still says "F: Compress components with gzip". When I inspect element (on Chrome) and look at the Headers in "Network", it says:

```
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
...
Server:nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
```

How can I tell if a file is being gzipped or not?

Answer (score 1):

If browser send `Accept-Encoding` header it tells to server: "Ok, you can send me gzip". And server if it configure to send gzip - send it. Browsers support gzip since 2000-2001 year, so now every browser support gzip. And you just need to configure your web server.

If you want to configure `gzip` on `Apache` web server add to `.htaccess` file this code:

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

If you use `nginx` as web static server, add to it config file:

```
gzip on;
gzip_comp_level 2;
gzip_http_version 1.0;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

# Disable for IE < 6 because there are some known problems
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)";

# Add a vary header for downstream proxies to avoid sending cached gzipped files to IE6
gzip_vary on;
```

P.S.: Full browser `gzip` support:

- Netscape 6+ (Netscape 4-5 does, but with some bugs).
- Internet Explorer 5.5+ (July 2000) and IE 4 if set to HTTP/1.1.
- Opera 5+ (June 2000)
- Lynx 2.6+ (some time before 1999)
- Firefox 0.9.5+ (October 2001)
- Chrome since forever
- Safari since forever

N.B.: IMHO `gipz` is helpful then request body is more than 3-5 kb size.